# Cython does not run properly

Tags: python, debian, cython

I have installed cython on Debian.But when i run cython from commmand line it raises this exception

```
ImportError: No module named Compiler.Main
```

And even when i write `from Cython.Compiler.Main import` main i get the same exception.
I can see that there is a Cython directory whereas Compiler.Main exist.I have not been able to figure out the reason behind the exception.

I tried installing/uninstalling Cython but i am not getting anywhere.

I tried to install using pip and apt-get both.I was installing it on debian squeeze.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version?
Are you isntalling it with apt-get or pip?

Comment: I tried to install it with pip and apt-get both.The version i don't know.